# App Scoped Id - Link to Facebook URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Previously - we were able to use the /account_id?acesss_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN to get the users information that authed in your app.

For the new v2.0 API, we get app_scoped_id where the folllowing method:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/APP_SCOPED_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Works for some users, but others - we get this:

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}`

Why would this function work for some users, but not others? We have no way to get the `link` property of the user to redirect them, nor does `http:///facebook.com/SCOPED_APP_ID` do anything or `http://facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/SCOPED_APP_ID` work correctly. Anyone  have advice to redirect the user to their FB profile via the FB Scope App ID?

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/APP_SCOPED_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` always works. Where are you getting the `APP_SCOPED_ID` from?

Comment: When the user logs in my app - we have valid APP_SCOPED_ID - otherwise how would we know be able to get their information? Here is an example of a single ID (69210119) that is not scoped and it says unsupported GET request.

Comment: How did you get that id then? If the id don't work it means that they are not a user of your app

Comment: If the user is identified with app scoped ID, why are you trying to fetch his info using the global?